# How to install Texmaker 4.0.1?

Tags: software-installation, deb, latex

I'm new to LaTeX, but want to get started for real; settled for Texmaker; now checked the version (and [changelog](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html)) and noticed a discrepancy between what I've got installed (3.4) and what's been released (4.0.1) -- just a few days ago.

I found an [outdated PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texmaker), but nothing else so far. So far, I've either installed things through Ubuntu or via a PPA, but hardly ever downloaded from a dev website, let alone compiled stuff from source.

1. Does anyone know of a PPA or an official Ubuntu way of *upgrading* to the latest release of Texmaker?
2. Are there any reasons I should *not* go ahead and simply [download](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) `Ubuntu 12.04 i386 package : texmaker_ubuntu_12.04_4.0.1_i386.deb (Qt4)` ?

Please provide some guidance or a link to a good discussion/explanation on *what to do a with a deb-file*... i.e.,

- How does it differ from directly installing through Ubuntu Software Center;
- What needs to be considered / taken care of / maintained;
- Why should one (generally) *avoid* a "manual" deb-installation (especially if one *does* trust the source)?

Answer (score 2):

The Software Center didn't have the latest texmaker as 4 days ago when I installed.  I downloaded and installed the amd64 version downloaded texmaker's website. I followed the instructions for Linux; that is, remove all previous version and install.

1. Download the most recent version (be sure to choose the correct version for your system: 32 or 64 bit): http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html
2. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter `sudo apt-get purge texmaker` to remove any previously installed version
3. Assuming the new version you just downloaded is in the Downloads folder, issue the following command in a terminal: `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/texmaker_ubuntu_*.deb`

Comment: Can you expand this to include a link to what you downloaded and a link to the instructions? (A summary of the important parts of the instructions would be an excellent addition, too.)

Comment: @dustin The download-link already is in my question; I'm interested in the ramifications of *installing a deb* (inter alia: how to and where to *uninstall* it again; does a manual deb-installation actually "talk to" **apt-get**, **synpatic**, etc? Do they know of their resp. (non-)existence?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty what I did was sudo apt-get purge texmaker and then I did sudo dpkg -i (deb file name for texmaker).  Everything works perfectly with not issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

Esay way is to use the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
```