# dpkg: error processing archive with texmaker

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg, latex

I am trying to install the latest version of texmaker, by following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/271665/412960). It failed and I tried some solutions posted on the internet like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/441049/412960), but with no luck!

Check my output:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ sudo dpkg -i Downloads/texmaker_ubuntu_14.04_4.4.1_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 380253 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../texmaker_ubuntu_14.04_4.4.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking texmaker (4.4.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive Downloads/texmaker_ubuntu_14.04_4.4.1_i386.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texmaker/doc6.png', which is also in package texmaker-data 4.1-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 Downloads/texmaker_ubuntu_14.04_4.4.1_i386.deb
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ sudo dpkg -P nginx-common
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove nginx-common which isn't installed
```

What I should do?

---

Edit: I removed the prev. installation:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ sudo apt-get purge texmaker
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'texmaker' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-windows-live asymptote asymptote-doc freeglut3 gdebi-core
  gksu latex-beamer latex-xcolor libgksu2-0 libgsl0ldbl liblouis-data
  liblouis2 libpoppler-qt4-4 libsigsegv2 libupstart1 linux-headers-3.16.0-30
  linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-40
  linux-headers-3.16.0-40-generic linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-40-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-40-generic pgf preview-latex-style prosper ps2eps
  python-imaging-tk python3-brlapi python3-louis python3-pyatspi
  python3-speechd texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils
  texlive-generic-recommended texlive-lang-english texlive-latex-extra
  texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-latex-recommended
  texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-pictures texlive-pictures-doc
  texlive-pstricks texlive-pstricks-doc texmaker-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
```

Comment: did you remove previous versions?

Comment: @Ron yes, check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force `dpkg` to over-write files by:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite Downloads/texmaker_ubuntu_14.04_4.4.1_i386.deb
```

Also run `sudo apt-get -f install` to make sure everything is OK.